# webDriver java selenium: if /else with asserttrue assertEquals and condition or /and

Tags: java, if-statement, webdriver

I search since 3 days now.

Hello

I want to verify that if condition1 AND condition2 is true OR condition3 AND condition4 is true, my test is Ok.

this code doesn't return error, the test runs passed but doesn't return the good message.
it return "KO, the color doesn't match with the status." instead of O"OK, the color is red and the status is NOK."
And i think that if the status doesn't match with the color, the test will be passed too (??)

Thanks for your help.

Isabelle.

*PS: you can answer in french !!*

//1 store the value of the status

```
String DisplayedStatus = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='eaDetails-ContentRegion-statustext']")).getText();
    System.out.println("the status displayed is: " + DisplayedStatus);
```

//2 store the color of the bar

```
String ColorRed = "rgb(227, 34, 25)";
    System.out.println("Red is: "+ColorRed);
String ColorGreen = "rgb(137, 186, 23)";
    System.out.println("Green is:"+ColorGreen);
String DisplayedStatusColor = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='eaDetails-ContentRegion-bar']")).getAttribute("style");
    //System.out.println("Styles of bar is: "+DisplayedStatusColor);
// keep bgcolor only
String BgColor1 = DisplayedStatusColor.split("background-color:")[1];
    //System.out.println("Color of bar is: "+BgColor1);
String BgColor = BgColor1.split(";")[0]; // remove the semi comma
    System.out.println("Color of bar is: "+BgColor);'
```

// check that "the bar is red and the status is NOK"    or    "the bar is green and status is OK".

```
 // assertTrue((BgColor.compareTo(ColorRed) == 0)&&(DisplayedStatus.compareTo("Status: NOK") == 0));      
 // assertTrue((BgColor.compareTo(ColorGreen) == 0)&&(DisplayedStatus.compareTo("Status: OK") == 0));

  if((BgColor.compareTo(ColorRed) == 0)&&(DisplayedStatus.compareTo("Status: NOK") == 0)){
        System.out.println("OK, the color is red and the status is NOK.");
  }
  else {
      if((BgColor.compareTo(ColorGreen) == 0)&&(DisplayedStatus.compareTo("Status: OK") == 0)){
            System.out.println("OK, the color is green and the status is OK.");
      }

      System.out.println("KO, the color doesn't match with the status.");
  } 
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code that works:

> // check that "the bar is red and the status is NOK"    or    "the bar
>   is green and status is OK".
>
> ```
>   String StatusIsOK = "Status: OK";
>   String StatusIsNOK = "Status: NOK";     
>
>   if(BgColor.equals(ColorRed)){
>   assertTrue(DisplayedStatus.compareTo(StatusIsNOK) == 0);
>   System.out.println("OK, the color is red and the status is NOK.");
>   }
>   else{
>       if(BgColor.equals(ColorGreen)){
>           assertTrue(DisplayedStatus.compareTo(StatusIsOK) == 0);
>           System.out.println("OK, the color is green and the status is OK.");
>       }
>       else{
>           System.out.println("FAILURE:  the color "+BgColor+" and the status "+DisplayedStatus+"  don't match.");
>       }           
>   }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with simpler dummy values, that way you will know where your if's behave as you expected. Every part of logic could be replaced with simpler. That way you could check if your if logic is correct.
Use simple steatment like

```
boolean condition1=false; boolean condition2=true;
```